# RESTful routing for registering, /register or /user/new?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have developed a website that allows users to register, however, my current route for registering is "/register". If I want my website to be RESTful, should I change "/register" to "/user/new"? What about "/login" and "/logout"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR -- both spellings are *fine*.

> If I want my website to be RESTful, should I change "/register" to "/user/new"?

No.

Changing the spelling of your resource identifiers won't make your website any more or less RESTful.  See Stefan Tilkov -- [REST: I don't Think it Means What You Think it Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

The spelling `/user/new` is consistent with the [Rails Routing conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions); so if you are expecting to onboard people who are familiar with the way that Rails does things, that might be an advantage.

The machines won't care.

In REST, we don't use resource identifier spellings to communicate resource semantics.  Instead, you get that from the context in which the identifier appears (link relations, human readable text, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

RESTful will response with JSON instead of view so its doesn't matter to change or not these route and you can use /register or /user/new both. but to make the code more readable and understandable i will suggest to keep

```
/register
/login
```

for logout it will mostly depend on front end that how the front end is saving user data like `token` and but you can still keep `/logout` on backend.